# "Help/Tutorial" page in WPF menu bar

Tags: wpf, text, menu, popup, photo

I've added a menu bar to application, because I wanted to add there a little tutorial under "Help" menu. Like Help - > "How to use the program", that's the idea.

I would like this to be, a pop up window that has ability to include text, as well as photos to better explain the program. It should be able to have a little bit of formatting (just a simple spaces, tabulator, new lines) so the text with photos looks clean.

To sum up, I need an idea, a tutorial, a guide, an adivce - you name it what should I use to implement those things, because right now I am in a blank spot.

@edit Hope this clarifies my question.

Comment: Love downvotes without even a comment. I am not asking for a solution or "ready to copy paste code", I am in totaly blank point and don't know where to look at.

Comment: I didn't downvote but i think the problem is that it's not really clear what you're asking. Do you want ideas on how to implement a help page or how to open one in a new window? Then you talk about using a popup control at the end. So your question is a bit confusing? It would probably be best if you ask about the mouseover highlight in a separate question or do a quick search since that question has been covered.

Comment: Alright, I'll edit my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this you need menu items:

```
<Window x:Class="WPFTestApp2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Menu>
            <MenuItem Header="Help">
                <MenuItem Header="How to use this program" Click="MenuItem_Click"></MenuItem>
            </MenuItem>
        </Menu>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And you would need a click handler:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WPFTestApp2
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void MenuItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            HelpWindow window = new HelpWindow();
            window.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

Then, you would need to create a new window with all the help text you would like.  You would need to design that window and I think that is really dependent on what the application does.

Comment: Damn, I think I really need to practice english a little more.. I mean, yeah I knew how to make popup window and I already have a menu. I really wanted to ask how to implement "window" in your code. How to add text there, how to add pictures there? Can I use designer to it?

Comment: That's kinda what we do as software developers.  You design it like any window.  Visual studio/blend is very good for designing WPF screens.  Just add a new window to your project and put some labels on there to get started

Comment: I recommend using common Microsoft standards as a help window.  It's a familiar place where users will not get *too* confused.